# Read Triangular Distribution Value from Database in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

Currently I am working on a project, where I need to read triangular distribution values for a delay/service block as the delay time.

The current setting is as follows,

1. The database is formatted as follows,
   [image]
2. The delay time is read from the dbase as follows,

[image]

Now I am looking for a method, so that I can input data in my dbase as triangular(1,2,3) instead of int 2.0. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Add a String column to the dbase, enter your "text" (`triangular(1,2,3)`).

Then load it into the model as a string and call `executeExpression(Double.class, myDbaseString)`

This will execute the string and return the double value from it.

HOWEVER: This is computationally *very* expensive and not a good idea if you plan to do this many times. If so, it is better to store the distribution type, and args as dbase columns and construct your distirbutions via code